# How much is the USA dependent on British and French support in international relations?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, international-relations, france

I know the relationship is mutually beneficial. But, I am trying to understand the depth of relations between the UK-France with the USA.

Can the USA function as smoothly as it is functioning in the area of international relations without British and French supports?

Kindly, give me some examples along with explanations.

Comment: You might clarify that the US is considerably more powerful, and could go it alone in many cases if it really wanted to. But that would be more difficult. This would be more "finds it beneficial to rely on" vs. "is dependent on."

Comment: @o.m.   Good point U.K. and French support is most important when the US seeks joint action.

Comment: @JMS, take the Iran example. Nobody doubts that the US could wreck the Iranian regime and nuclear program unilaterally. They are not prepared to pay the price unilaterally.

Comment: @o.m.  Actually there is no good military option on Iran’s nuclear program.  Which is why the US has preferred the sanction route.  And to do sanctions it requires consensus and allies

Comment: @JMS, agreed, no *good* options. But there are *bad* military options and the cost of those might be shared.

Comment: I would not mix France and UK, while UK in more taht 90% suports USA, France can have a diferent opinion, the best example was Irak war 2003.

Answer (score 6):

### Question:

> How much is the USA dependent on British and French support in international relations?

### Answer

While no nation has a closer alliance with the United States than the UK, France's history with the United States is different and a bit more contentious at times.  The UK and France are among the United States most important allies.

1. Both are liberal democracies which generally have common concerns with the US on international issues.
2. Both are on the UN Security Council and that means nothing substantial goes through the UN without their agreement.  Both have veto's on any substantive UN action.
3. Both are important NATO allies who drill, coordinate and consult with the US on defense.  NATO is America's most important ally and Europe is a region which America twice has gone to war over (WWI, WWII).
4. Both along with the United State have the 3 most capable militaries able to project power removed from their borders more than any other nations including Russia and China.  So If the US were to go to war removed from their common boarders no other two countries would have the ability to support the US militarily than the UK and France.
5. The UK and France along with the United States are among the top eight largest economies in the world, another important group for international relations and decision making.
6. The UK is the closest ally the United States has.  It's among the five eyes allies made up of the UK, the US and some of the UK's commonwealth nations.  This group by treaty shares a special relationship with regards to security assets including raw signals intelligence, technology and many sensitive defense secrets shared with no other US allies.
7. When Iraq invaded Kuwait ultimately resulting in the first gulf war.  Then American President George H W Bush decided to go to war largely on the strong advice of British PM Margaret Thatcher.  She was so respected among American political leadership at that time that her say so was enough to convince them to go to war.  In interviews prior to his meeting with Thatcher President Bush and his advisors were not pursuing military action.   It was Thatcher who convinced Bush that Saddam's aggression should not be permitted to stand.   Appeasing aggression yields more aggression.  I've read that from several different sources.

- **[Oral History: Margaret Thatcher](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/gulf/oral/thatcher/1.html)**

Comment: Point of information: the USA has never "gone to war over Europe", although the Cold War and the extended occupation of West Germany was very close to it. In the case of the two World Wars, America entered the war because Germany or its allies had struck at or threatened its interests.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd to be fair I said  Europe was a “region” America has twice gone to war over tO limit these kinds of disputes.  Clearly America has huge interests in Europe.  And clearly the us has gone to war there and kept troops there to protect those interests.  I would argue keeping the knowledge, Capital, culture, ambitions and populations of Europe under represetative formS of government and free is what WWI, WWII, and Cold War were about.  Perhaps you can suggest a rewording which better fits.

Comment: The feeling in the UK is that the USA barely even shares a common language any more, let alone traditional values. If you were to reword it, I'd suggest something along the lines of "in support of allies in Europe" but the popular feeling is that America only entered WW-I when Germany's defeat was a forgone conclusion and wouldn't have entered WW-II (irrespective of Roosevelt's preference) if it hadn't been for Pearl Harbour... which was pretty much guaranteed to happen sooner or later after America had encouraged Japan to expand in the Far East.

Comment: I would say that Glaspie's lack of 'clarity' was one of the reasons for the first gulf war.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd   What I was going for is regardless of why the US entered in two World Wars and Stationed troops in Europe and entered into its first and only broad multi-nation defense pact/organization all demonstrate how important Europe was and remains to US interests.  Current administration insinuations aside, and also setting aside how popular or not various transient U.S. administrations have been in Europe.

Comment: First bullet point is incorrect. UN Security Council vetos only affect decisions by the Security Council. The UN as a whole also has the General Assembly where resolutions are decided upon by a majority of states (50 % plus one vote) or 2/3 in important cases as decided by the Assembly. The veto powers have no means of stopping a General Assembly resolution and it is these that would likely be considered the UN’s actions. (However, the Security Council is responsible for things such as peacekeeping forces.)

Comment: Second bullet point: France and the NATO have a somewhat complicated history and while the French are currently a member they did not subject their nuclear submarines to NATO command. Others have raised the point about the wording of ‘Going to war over’. There are plenty of possible, not unlikely timelines in which the US would not have joined World War I – and indeed, when they finally did there wasn’t much left to decide. It seems to me that the phrase applies the late 20th-century US military power and internationalist doctrine to times before it was a thing.

Comment: @Jan  regardless France is the second most capable military in NATO and perhaps the world with regards to projecting power.  Everyone wants to discuss why the US got involved in the world wars.  The only point relevant to my answer is the fact America did go to war there!  In US history those were the first two foreign wars the US joined in 150 years.  Clearly Europe is important to the US. No argument here for it was in US interest.  Doesn’t really matter why the US did it.

Comment: @Jan  the 5 permanent members of the security council have the ability to veto any “[substantive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_veto_power) resolution by the United Nations.  The general assemble cannot take any substantive action without at least the tacit approval of all 5 permanent security council members.  That’s why the UN often fails to act because there is disagreement among the security council members.

Comment: @JMS Congratulations: You linked to a page describing a mechanism *of the Security Council*. Again, the Security Council is only *one branch* of the United Nations and Security Council vetos *do not* affect the General Assembly. With the exception of recommending the Secretary-General, a Security Council vote has no bearing on the General Assembly.

Comment: @Jan   Horse water drink,  I quoted the source and provided the link.  All “substantive” resolutions!  The general assemble can take no “substantive” action without the tacit agreement of all 5 permanent security council members.

Comment: @JMS Jeez, you better edit [United Nations General Assembly resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_resolution) and [United Nations General Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly) to include your newly found research. Better inform the UN HQ too, they may be unaware of this new development!

Comment: @JMS You might also be interested to find out that [this infamous General Assembly resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_3379) was enacted by simple majority vote despite three out of five veto powers voting against (which in the Security Council would have thrown out the resolution because it’s an effing veto power).

Comment: I think you need to separate out France and the UK as allies because the US has been much closer to the UK then to France, and the French Governments are far more likely to not work with the US government then the UK, such as during the Iraq war France refused to allow US military planes fly in French airspace.

Comment: @TheFoxandtheGoldenLadder, All very true, and as I said the UK is the United States closest ally.  France is not.   But I would still say France and the UK are both among the United States most important allies per the reasons given.   The question groups them so I followed suit in my answer,  even though you are correct the relationships are very different.

Answer (score 4):

The [JCPOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action) is a good example, even if three other countries were involved (China, Russia, Germany).

- Working with Europe, China and Russia, the United States pressured Iran into a deal which froze their uranium enrichment in exchange for sanctions reduction. Various US agencies certified that Iran kept *that* narrow agreement, while working against Western interests in many other areas.
- Later on, working *against* Europe, the United States tried to pressure Iran into going beyond the reductions agreed in the JCPOA. As a result, Iran is again enriching uranium beyond 3.67%.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be less and less. The United States is gradually leaving the world's leading position.
The Cold War is long gone, and the United States and Europe will care more about their own interests.

Comment: I think that a weakening position implies MORE dependency on allies. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @fraxinus The weakening position corresponds to a strategic contraction, which is why the US is withdrawing its troops from the Middle East and reducing its garrison in Europe. The strategic differences between the United States and Europe can be reflected in the recent Iranian arms embargo. The US's influence in Europe has weakened.